# How to dynamically load JavaScript files and use best lazy loading practices in web

Tags: javascript, import, dynamic, lazy-loading

How can I dynamically load JavaScript files based on user interactions in my web application? What are the best practices for lazy loading in JavaScript?

I've been working on optimizing the loading of JavaScript files in my web application. To achieve dynamic loading, I attempted to use the import() function along with dynamic import statements to load specific modules based on user interactions. For example, I tried:

```
const handleClick = async () => {
  const dynamicModule = await import('./path/to/module.js');
  // Further logic to use the dynamically loaded module
};
```

I expected that the `import()` function would allow me to dynamically load JavaScript files when a specific user action, such as a button click (handleClick function in the example), occurs. My goal is to improve the initial loading time by only fetching and executing the necessary code when needed.

Comment: How big are your JavaScript files that a singular minified version of your source code is less preferable or materially less performant than incurring the overhead of multiple roundtrip requests to the server for several files instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersection observer for lazy loading

```html
let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      // Load the component
      import('./lazyComponent.js').then(module => {
        // Initialize or display the component
        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
      });
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.lazy-load-component'));
```

This is for lazy loading ui componenets